How to fetch Stack Exchange API question and comment body content while avoiding 429 errors?
I am trying to fetch data from the Stack Overflow API for a project that analyzes Java-related questions.
The problem is that I cannot retrieve the body content of questions or comments even when using the withbody filter. Additionally, my code occasionally encounters a 429 Too Many Requests error.
Here's what I have tried so far:

Reduced the number of concurrent threads.
Adjusted the sleep time dynamically based on quota_remaining.


You've asked two questions here. Please [edit] your question so you are only asking one. If you want both questions answered, then ask a second Question with the other question. Your two questions appear to be: "How can I avoid getting a 429 response when making requests to the SE API?" and "How can I retrieve the body contents of questions or comments?" For the second question, we're going to need more information, including the exact requests you are making (obviously, without any access_token that you might be using).
